# Solving $2\cos \left( \frac{\pi }{2}-\theta \right)=3\cos \left( \frac{\pi }{3}+\theta \right)$ for $0 < θ < 2π$

Tags: trigonometry

I am required to solve this equation:

> Find all the angles that satisfy the equation $$2\cos \left( \frac{\pi }{2}-\theta  \right)=3\cos \left( \frac{\pi }{3}+\theta  \right)$$
> for $0 < θ < 2π$

I am aware that I can convert $$\cos \left( \frac{\pi }{3}+\theta  \right)=\cos\frac{\pi }{3}\cos\theta-\sin\frac{\pi }{3}\sin\theta$$ and $$\cos \left( \frac{\pi }{2}-\theta  \right)=\sin\theta$$ .

So,
$$2\cos \left( \frac{\pi }{2}-\theta  \right)=3\cos \left( \frac{\pi }{3}+\theta  \right)$$
$$2\sin\theta =3\left( \cos\frac{\pi }{3}\cos\theta-\sin\frac{\pi }{3}\sin\theta \right)$$

I stuck here,

If anyone can explain to me how to achieve this I would be very grateful.

Comment: Arrange the terms so that the equation is in the form $a\sin \theta +b\sin\theta=c$, then solve it with your favourite method.

Comment: It's not even the same question, therefore I've restored your original question so that more people can answer it. Questions need 5 votes to be reopened and I've just voted to reopen.

Comment: In future, please do not delete/change the question, except to make edits to your original question. It only makes it harder for us to do the right thing and figure out how we can best help. I've also added a request to reopen this question on the meta site [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2021-today/34194#34194): if you find yourself in this situation again, you can add a new request there by 'answering' the question.

Comment: @TobyMak why you reopen this post?? I am so sorry because I wrote wrong question and I assume all answer in this post not helpfull and useless. I want to delete this post so I ask new question asap.

Comment: The question isn't just for you, but for everyone else in the community. It's a good example of when to use the property $\cos(\pi/2 - \theta) = \sin \theta$, which is useful for the millions of people who are studying trigonometry.

Comment: Besides, more (well-asked) questions give you more reputation, which gives you more privileges on this site.

Comment: @TobyMak yes you true.. but its wrong that I ask wrong question . I felt GUILTY :(

Comment: It's natural to make mistakes. In fact, everyone makes mistakes. If you like, you can check out some of my old answers and questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/285313/toby-mak?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=29) which aren't that good.

Comment: @TobyMak hmm okay

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comments.